# Error de publicación ASP.NET en IIS (Windows 10)

Tags: asp.net, iis

Quisiera pedir su ayuda, me han proporcionado un proyecto desarrollado en ASP.NET, núnca había trabajado con el por lo que he investigado cómo publicarlo y ya encontré que es con IIS, tengo un actual error en el **web.config.**

> *Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error No se puede obtener acceso a la página solicitada porque los datos de configuración relacionados
>   de la página no son válidos.*
>
> *Error de configuración      No se puede agregar una entrada de colección duplicada de tipo 'add' con un atributo de clave única
>   'name' establecido en 'Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd'*

El proyecto por lo que veo es del año 2015 y no estoy seguro si esto sea el problema.
Utilizando los manuales que dejaron los desarrolladores, dice que se debe montar en el IIS, dentro del Sitio Web Default, utilzando un directorio virtual.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, o si tienen alguna otra forma de configurar el IIS se los agradeceré.
**De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo**

Comment: Claro, Los valores de los web config se heredan por lo cual si tenés un web config padre con esa línea y la escribís de nuevo en tu web config te queda una clave duplicada. Probá comentando esa línea. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error es que por alguna razón en el archivo web.config correspondiente a la app que intentas publicar esta duplicada una entrada en los web handlers, puedes darle un ojo al siguiente enlace que contiene información acerca de este tipo de issues https://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-web-ui-webresource-axd-and-web-config-once-and-for-all

adicionalmente te exhorto a que verifiques si el web.config padre (en IIS) no contiene dicha linea, deberías de tener solo una linea (desde el pare hasta los hijos) similar a esta:

```
<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd"
 type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"
 verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
```